# applying future where can be exception comes

Tags: multithreading, scala, playframework, thread-safety, future

this code works fine but i want to manage threads, by `Future`.
`sendSMS` method takes normally 3 to 5 seconds to execute, i want to applying future and applied at one place but want to know is it enough or not?

```
val c = for {
            t <- Future { doSendSms("+9178787878787","i scare with threads") }
          } yield t
c.map { res =>
        res match {
          case e: Error => {
            Ok(write(Map("result" -> "error")))
          }
          case Success() => {
            Ok(write(Map("result" -> "success")))
          }

def doSendSms(recipient: String, body: String): SentSmsResult = {
    try {
      sendSMS(recipient, body)
      Success()
    } catch {
      case twilioEx: TwilioRestException =>
          return Error(twilioEx.toString)
      case e: Exception =>
          return Error(e.toString)
    }
  }


def sendSMS(smsTo: String, body: String) = {
    val params = Map("To" -> smsTo, "From" -> twilioNumber, "Body" -> body)
    val messageFactory = client.getAccount.getSmsFactory
    messageFactory.create(params)
  }// sending sms from twilio, this method takes 3 to 5 seconds to execute
```

if not how to manage Future in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`recover`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html):

```
val c = for {
  t <- doSendSms("+9178787878787","i scare with threads")
} yield t

def doSendSms(recipient: String, body: String): Future[SentSmsResult] = 
  Future {
    sendSMS(recipient, body)
  }
  .recover {
    case twilioEx: TwilioRestException => Error(twilioEx.toString)
    case e: Exception => Error(e.toString)
  }
}
```

`recover` will catch exceptions thrown in the future execution allowing you to return a new result wrapped in a `Future`, as the documentation states:

> The recover combinator creates a new future which holds the same result as the original future if it completed successfully. If it did not then the partial function argument is applied to the Throwable which failed the original future.

Comment: but `Error(e.toString)` should be `Future(Error(e.toString))`

Comment: Actually no, if you see the example on the documentation `val purchase: Future[Int]` the `recover` is so defined: `recover { case QuoteChangedException() => 0 }`, also lookup the recover definition [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/42899b1850fd56c5e4d75d9d4c3f7509abf54d6d/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala), you see that the return type is already a future.

Comment: I can't test the types but this error happens because `Error` is not of type `SentSmsResult`, you will have to think if `recover` is what you want to use since the main usage is to provide a result even though the future failed, for example if there's some sort of exception you may want to return a `SentSmsResult` that indicates that the sms was not sent and then use that result later on, this is what the `recover` method enforces. If you don't want to then you can stick with try/catch but as far as I know this is the scala way with futures.

Comment: actualy, i am doing with 'return' thats why that comes.

Comment: Yeah but remember that the type you return must conform to the function signature, if your signature returns a `Future[Int]`, `recover` must also return a `Future[Int]`, in your case I suspect that `Error` is not of type `SentSmsResult`.

Comment: I am getting one more error in `case Success() => {` that is
`constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : controllers.Twilio.Success required: scala.concurrent.Future[Product with Serializable with controllers.Twilio.SentSmsResult]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58609/discussion-between-govind-singh-nagarkoti-and-ende-neu).